# Bluetooth Headphones: Listening to 2 Sources Simultaneously

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

According to [this website](https://productsbrowser.com/best-cheap-wireless-earbuds-reviews/), there are headhpones where "you can connect two phones at the same time." This as in the headphones can receive audio from two sources simultaneous (e.g. two phones).

Is this a feature of Bluetooth specifically or only these headphones. Either way, how would you go about doing this?

**How would you connect two separate devices to the same bluetooth headphones so that you can receive audio from both?**